# Trying to figure out database table relations (Rails / ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I am building a web app over the next 2 weeks that aims to connect Music Students with Music Instructors.

This will all be done using Ruby on Rails with ActiveRecord database

I am trying to plan out my database with proper relations and want to make sure everything is good to go before moving forward.

My thought was to have a `user` to `user` interaction.

This would include the following columns:

> - first name (string)
> - last name (string)
> - location (string)
> - mobile (boolean)
> - bio (text)
> - email (string)
> - password (string)

The associations in the models for each would be something like

> - class Student
> - has_many :teachers, through: :tutorships
> - has_many :instruments

Then

> - class Teacher
> - has_many :students, through: :tutorships
> - has_many :instruments

Then a instruments table

> - instrument (string)
> - skill_level (integer) *using enum in model to associate with beginner, intermediate & advanced
> - Model would be (belongs_to (:student / :teacher)

Then the join table between the Users would be a tutorship table:

> - belongs_to :student
> - belongs_to :teacher
> - has_many :lessons

Then a lesson table

> - belongs_to :tutorship

So, this is what I have so far. My question is, when I am setting up my migrations in Rails, am I going to be missing anything in my tables?

I think I need to be putting something like, `t.belongs_to :student` but since it is a `user` to `user` relationship that feels off.

What am I missing here? I know something is amiss.

Comment: I wonder if the `tutorship` table needs a reference to `instruments` too. IMHO if both students and teachers might have multiple instruments, then it might be unclear what instrument to teach in a specific tutorship? Or is it up to the tutor to just choose one?

Comment: Hmm. What do you mean, or better put - how would it be implemented in your view?

I was thinking that both `student` and `teacher` would have an `instrument / skill level` tied to them and then they would link up because of a mutual interest. Maybe I am thinking of this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

SQL databases are highly normalized, but you are of course allowed to copy the student and teacher ids into the lesson, thus denormalize, and for performance gains there's a good reason to do that.

Actually there's a case where this is a good idea, think of a teacher being sick and one lesson being taught by a replacement teacher. No need to create a new Tutorship, just assign a different teacher for that one lesson.

Something you are missing is of course timestamps/dates.

Answer (score 0):

You will only need to add `t.belongs_to :student`to the tutorships and instruments tables, not to teachers, if it is that what you are wondering.

You many want to add some status columns to differentiate active/former/... on students and teachers